# why doesn't download window appear in browser for long when I export data

Tags: php, zend-framework, export, export-to-csv

I try export data from database to .csv. When I click export link I don't see save window in browser for a very long time if there is quite a lot amount of data. It can be quite confusing if the script looks like hanging for some time and after quite a long time one can see save window in browser.
The code is something like this in controller:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        $fileName = $list->list_name . '.csv';

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8')
                            ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"');      

        $contacts = new Contact();
        $contacts->export($listId);
```

Export method reads records one by one and prints it something like this:

```
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');        
    foreach ($mongodbCursor as $subscriber) {
           $row = formRow($subscriber);
       fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }
```

I see on some applications that save winow appear almost immediately and when you click save you see progress of downloading.

I tried to replace:

```
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8')
                        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"');
```

with this one:

```
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"');
```

It didn't help so far.
I wonder if it's possible to send headers before all data are read one by one from database? 
Thank your for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I'm not familiar with php://output, my application writes my information with fopen,fwrite,fclose to a temporary file afterwards I give it out with similiar header(); options.

```
            $filesize = filesize("tmp/export.csv");
            header("Content-Type: text/csv");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"export.csv\"");
            header("Conent-Length: $filesize");
            readfile("tmp/export.csv");
            unlink("tmp/export.csv");
            exit;
```

This one gives the download window of your browser instantly.

Comment: What max size of file did you export like this?

Comment: I don't understand you right now, what import? This piece of code is to give out the cvs the same script wrote a few lines above it. Max filesize is unlimited (in my case it reads database entries, no problems even when exporting thousands of entries at once)

Comment: In your code, I see only ouputing contents of some file, right? There is not code of getting it from database. I meant that if getting all data from database is long, it could take quite a long time to write it to temporary file which you ouput later, right? So the user will not see download window until all data has been taken from database.

Comment: Not really, tested with about 2000 inventory items (about 30 database fields of varchar(128)) CSV was made in just a second.

Comment: The issues take place if you have 500K or 1M items. Until all data are read from database, the user will not see download window.

Comment: There's no way to improve the script more, for such heavy things you need an optimized webserver or maybe better hardware to improve the speed more and more.

Comment: Maybe you just want to add some little javascript loading screen to bypass a few seconds?

Comment: I think there should be some way to display dowload window quickly, giving user some feedback, and output data from database could take quite a lot of time, maybe several minutes or so.

Comment: You really can't do that quicker

Comment: I don't quite understand idea about javascript loading. I don't think something it will help.

Comment: I don't need to make exporting quicker, I need to display download quicker. If I send header, I think it should cause to display browser window faster.

Comment: It can't help, it's just to show the user that the server is working so he does'nt rape the F5 key. I give up. It's not possible to gain more speed but you won't accept that.

Comment: Do you mean I can't display download window faster and why?

Comment: What speed do you mean? Do you mean that I can't display download window faster. I'm not talking about making download file faster, I'm talking about giving feedback by the window, while data are loaded. If it takes to get all data from database 3 minutes, the user don't see download window. Isn't possible to changed this?

Comment: Doesn't sending headers to browser make it popup this window, sending data afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do this:

- call the header function instead of `$this->getResponse()->setHeader()` (the response content might be saved in a buffer and outputed only when it is completed - the time the export finishes)
- try to echo the content directly instead of writing to php://output (if you set the headers before that, everything you echo will be placed in the generated CSV file)

EDIT

Replace `fputcsv` with a function like `print_row` below

```
function print_row($row) {
        echo '"' . implode('","', $row) . '"' . "\r\n"; 
}
```

The function gets the first parameter as an array, adds `"` and `,` and echoes to content.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to replace:   $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');    fputcsv($fp, $row); What do you mean echo directly? Do you mean to echo fields values, commands, new lines manually?

Comment: Yes, I mean you can echo directly each CSV line something like `"value","value2"\r\n` . I will edit the answer and add a sample function that you could use.

Comment: I tried to replace with header functions instead of methods of response class, it didn't help now.

Comment: Ok, good. Try to replace also `fputcsv` to `php://output` with the function above and let's see if there is a more significant improvement.

Comment: I tried to replace it with echo '"' . implode('","', $row) . '"' . "\r\n";. I don't display download window fast, the page is hanging for some time and only when data are loaded, displays a download window, I click ok and get file instantly after it.

Comment: It seems rather strange for me.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Check the connection and the time it takes for the server to respond. If it is not that, try to do some profiling on that page to see why it takes so long to respond (maybe waits for the db to perform the query?). You could also consider caching the content if it is not changed frequently. Anyway, I would recommend to keep the changes you have made so far.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean: "Check the connection and the time it takes for the server to respond. If it is not that, try to do some profiling on that page to see why it takes so long to respond (maybe waits for the db to perform the query?)."

Comment: Check with firebug the time it usually takes the server to respond to a request. (if the server is on your local machine you can skip that). Next try to do PHP profiling (e.g. `http://xdebug.org/`) to see exactly how much time it takes for the server to execute the script and what operations are the most time consuming. Next see if you can optimize any SQL queries you are executing. And if the content is not changed frequently, write the CSV to a file on the  server. Next time the page loads, check if there is any file written that has not expired (cached) and print that directly.

Comment: I firebug, I see thet my headers are not returned for long, when they are sent, download window appears.

Comment: In firebug, I see thet my headers are not returned for long, when they are sent, download window appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
// $file = path of file

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Could you please explain your idea and what's wrong with my code?

Comment: My idea forces download from a file-link, and I have no idea what's wrong with your code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Could you please tell, why in manual they ob_clean();
flush(); after setting headers?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `application/force-download` instead of `text/csv` in your `Content-Type` value.

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"" . $fileName . "\"");
```

This will force an actual download box instead of just showing the content *in* the browser.

Here is some documentation from [MIME Application](http://mimeapplication.org/force-download.html):

> Mime application/force-download, which is typically expressed as mime application/x-force-download, is typically used in conjunction with PHP code to trigger a download box rather than for displaying content in a Web browser.
>
> For example, if you had a file on your website that you want the user to download rather than view in the Web browser, you could enter the appropriate mime application/force-download code in the file’s header content type field. Note that mime application/force-download is not a registered MIME type. In addition, when used in PHP code, the preferred spelling of mime application/force-download contains the “x-” prefix.

Comment: Do you mean to use headers like this: header('Content-Type: application/force-download; charset=utf-8');        
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"');

Comment: It seems to the the problem is that my headers are sent only after getting data from database, during this time headers are not sent to client. So I'm not sure it's a problem with some kind of header, since they are not sent for quite a long time. It doesn't seem a standard mime which could cause many issues,

Comment: Of course headers are sent once the page has finish rendering. You seem to face two differents problems here. The initial question was how to prompt a download box, which I answered. If you want to improve your CSV generation time, you should post another question and join any relevant code. But yes, first, PHP fetchs data from your database, then, it generates a CSV file. Headers are sent **only after**  everything has finished.

Comment: You write: "The initial question was how to prompt a download box, which I answered." I don't understand advantage your headers give, I tried what you suggested: header('Content-Type: application/force-download; charset=utf-8'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"'); And I don't see any advantage of them to what I use: header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"');

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this a good solution, I didn't explore it much, but it seems it's working.
It cotroller after I add some data to buffer after headers, before exporting.

```
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"');

    echo str_pad('', ini_get('output_buffering'));      
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    Model_Subscriber1::exportList($listId);
```

To make it works in controller I added in Zend Bootstrap.php:

```
/**
 * hint to the dispatcher that it should not use output buffering to capture output generated by action controllers.
 *  By default, the dispatcher captures any output and appends it to the response object body content. 
 */
protected function _initFront()
{
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->setParam('disableOutputBuffering', 1);        
}
```

It look like in this case I get download window in browser quickly and then data are exporting which could take quite a long time. I don't know if this solution is acceptable now. I'd be glad to here your opinion about it.
It cause issues with adding empty data to export file.
So, I change it controller to.

```
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName . '"');

    Model_Subscriber1::exportList($listId);
```

And chang function for export to something like this:

```
  foreach ($mongodbCursor as $subscriber) {
           $row = formRow($subscriber);
    echo '"' . implode('","', $row) . '"' . "\r\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();                    

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function may want to call flush / ob_flush just before long operation and let the HTTP header send to client before long process.